# Update CAE linux to latest Ubuntu OS that has been installed with windows 7

Tags: windows-7, linux, installation

I have installed Windows within CAE linux. Can I update linux safely so that the windows OS is not disturbed ??? CAE linux is the primary OS.

Comment: Are you running Windows in a VM? If so, no amount of updating your host OS will effect the VM. Your virtual machine manager may get updated but it should not effect the virtual image whatsoever.

Comment: Looks like you've got a registered and unregistered account. Please use the "contact us" link to request an account merger.